# How to make a RecyclerView onClickListener display another RecyclerView

Tags: android, json

I am trying to start a new Recycler view upon clicking a container view from another recycler view. Essentially I have a list of NBA teams presented as a recycler view in `NBA_Adapter;` when each team is clicked it will bring the user to another recycler view showing the players in the team. I am trying to do this using two classes that extend the recycler view. The issue is that I am unable to start the second class, which I suspect is because the second class does not extend `AppCompatActivity` and instead extends RecyclerView, which the manifest file is asking me to do since it does not recognize my second class. Manifest below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nba">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Second_Adapter">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

         </intent-filter>
</activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Main Activity below:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //instantiates the parameters
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        
        adapter = new NBA_Adapter(getApplicationContext());
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    }

  
}
```

Part of 1st Class below:

```
 @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TEAMS current = (TEAMS) containerView.getTag();

                    
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Second_Adapter.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", current.getId());

                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
```

My second class is essentially the same as in my first class. The only reason I do not use the same recycler view is that I am having a hard time implementing it as I am also using a search view for each recycler view. So at the moment, I am separating them.